# MS Word: Changing selection to a custom style affects entire paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I have a document with some custom styles. One of them just has bold, but it happens regardless of the custom style I choose.

When I select a word within a line/paragraph (currently set to the built-in normal style) and then select the custom style, it changes the entire paragraph, not just the selected word.

It didn't used to be like this when I worked on the document before and could set words independently so I have obviously changed something by accident but no idea what. I've tried clearing formatting for the entire paragraph.

If it helps, the style type says: "Linked (paragraph and character)" but it's greyed out so I can't change it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bring up the Styles dialog box (e.g. alt-ctrl-shift-S), if "Disable Linked Styles" is checked, uncheck it.

This makes linked styles behave like Paragraph Styles - otherwise they behave like Character styles when applied to part of a paragraph.